# ¿Cómo obtener el codigo fuente de un Url abierto en chrome desde python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, cabeceras-http, url

Lo que busco es si es que hay una forma de obtener el código fuente (html) de una URL que ya está abierta en el navegador web (Chrome).

Busco hacer esto mismo:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = response.read()
```

Pero con una página abierta desde el navegador.

Me explico: Ese código me funciona perfecto, pero hay algunos casos donde requiero entrar usando user/password a ciertas páginas.
Previamente sin que mi usuario y contraseñas quedaran registradas en el navegador, no podía ver la totalidad el html de la página, pero luego de entrar con el usuario y contraseña, es posible ver todo el html que busco.

Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿cómo hacer para obtener el html usando un navegador predeterminado?
Para así cuando ejecute el código, sólo tenga que registrarme previamente y me asegure ver todo el html.

Comment: En vez de intentar obtenerlo de Chrome, ¿no te conviene imitar lo que hace Chrome para obtener la página? Es decir, ¿no sería más directo enviarle los datos que necesites enviarle al servidor para que te devuelva la página como si estuvieras logueado?

Comment: Eso mismo se podría hacer usando `requests` o `urllib2`. Si pones la url a la que quieres acceder podemos intentar ponerte un ejemplo.

Comment: @kikocorreoso Estoy tratando de hacerlo desde Instagram. El problema es que tiene ciertos niveles de seguridad en cuanto a enviar datos desde un código externo

Comment: Instagram tiene una API. Es el camino correcto. Lo demás podría ser tomado como ilícito y te podrían bloquear. En sus [ToS](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:L3jbkEt-NBwJ:https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511+&cd=1&hl=es&ct=clnk&gl=es&client=firefox-b) indican "We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with Instagram's express consent)."

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo usar [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). Creo que te permite hacer lo que pretendes: Entrar a una página en concreto, rellenar los campos de acceso (usuario y password) y acceder a la página con el usuario validado. Una vez dentro, podrás obtener el código fuente de la página ya validada.

Más info, aquí:

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Un [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275955/how-to-download-a-webpage-that-require-username-and-password) en StackOverflow:

Comment: Hola, el ejemplo no me da una solución, ya que la página a la cual trato de acceder no me genera los _forms_ necesarios para acceder a los inputs

Comment: Con eso no contaba... ¿Es una web pública a la que podamos acceder para buscar posibles alternativas?